# IE 11 not working with JQuery

Tags: json, internet-explorer

m working with Asp.Net Web Services and Json-JQuery. My code is simple: 
Load aspx page. Click a button and call a web service.

It works perfectly in Chrome but doesnt in IE11. Even if i execute in browser console a simple JQuery script like $(btnguardar) ie returns undefined, chrome instead returns the button.

Is there a solution for this?

Here is my code: 
(aspx file)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/wprincipal.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="winicio.aspx.vb" Inherits="winicio" Culture="es-MX" ViewStateMode="Disabled" ClientIDMode="Static" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<script src="Script/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
        .style1
    {
        width: 159px;
    }
</style></asp:Content><asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tsm" runat="server" EnableScriptLocalization="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="style1">

          Nombre </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtnombre" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1">

           Apellido </td>
        <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="Txtapellido" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1">

           Estado </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataTextField="Descripcion" 
                DataValueField="IdEstado">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfestado" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1">
            Fecha</td>
        <td>
           <asp:TextBox id="txtfecha" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="dtpick" runat="server" EnabledOnClient="true" TargetControlID="txtfecha"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1">

           Observacion </td>
        <td>
           <asp:TextBox id="txtobservacion" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="style1">
        <input type="button" id="btnretroceder" value="<" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" id="btnAvanzar" value=">" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" id="btnguardar" value="Guardar" />
    </td></tr>
</table>
<asp:HiddenField ID="idcliente" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var ax = document.getElementById("txtfecha");
    ax.readOnly = true;

    var frm = document.getElementById("form1");
    if (frm) {
        frm.onsubmit = function () { return false; };
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(btnAvanzar).click(function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "wsClientes.asmx/ConsultarClienteJSON",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                },
                error: AjaxFailed
            });
        });
    });
    function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
        var datos = eval('(' + result.d + ')');
        if (datos) {
            document.getElementById("txtnombre").value = datos.Nombre;
            document.getElementById("Txtapellido").value = datos.Apellido;
            $(DropDownList1).val(datos.IdEstatus);
            var a = new Date(Date(datos.FechaCaptura.substring(datos.FechaCaptura.indexOf('(') + 1, datos.FechaCaptura.indexOf(')'))));
            document.getElementById("txtfecha").value = a.getDate() + '/' + (a.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + a.getFullYear();
            document.getElementById("txtobservacion").value = datos.Observacion;
        }
    }

   function AjaxFailed(result) {
        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }
</script>
```

and here is the web service:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json


<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ScriptService()>
Public Class wsClientes
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function ConsultarClienteJSON() As String
    Dim cls As New Datos.Usuarios.clsClientes

    Dim memstr As New IO.MemoryStream

    cls.Obtener_Clientes_AProp()

    Return Serialize(cls)

End Function

Public Shared Function Serialize(Of T)(obj As T) As String
    Dim serializer As New DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.[GetType]())
    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream()
    'serializer.
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj)
    Dim retVal As String = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray())
    retVal = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())
    Return retVal
End Function

End Class
```

Thanks

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I'd try a more recent version of JQuery. Is there a reason why you've stuck with 1.4?

Comment: I was using the included with Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Look at the HTML source, you will spot the problem with the id...

Answer (score 1):

found out that

```
$(btnAvanzar)
```

is supported in chrome and firefox. But Internet Explorer requires the following syntax

```
$("#btnAvanzar")
```

other way to do it is

```
$(document.getElementById("btnAvanzar"))
```

however it takes too much to write

Thanks for your colaboration